# Popup menu checkbox won't

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a popup menu with two checkboxs but when I press either of them the menu just disappears and nothing changes in their state. I've looked around and found things that work for other people but they don't work for me

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{


    if(item.isChecked())
    {
        item.setChecked(false);
    }
    else
    {
        item.setChecked(true);
    }
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.lockscreen:
            if(item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            break;
        case R.id.notif:
            if(item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


    return true;
}
```

This the XML for the menu

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item android:id="@+id/lockscreen"
        android:title="Lockscreen"
        android:checked="false"
        android:checkable="true"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/notif"
        android:title="Notification"
        android:checked="false"
        android:checkable="true"/>

</group>
```

Comment: try setselection  method like element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

Comment: That doesn't work as I'm not using a list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(item.isChecked()) {
    item.setChecked(false);
}
else {
    item.setChecked(true);
}
```

These lines seem to instantly uncheck the item if it was checked before…
What are you trying to do in this if-else construct?
Just comment it out and let the other if-statements do all the work (those in the `case`s).

Comment: Thats seem to have done it, don't know why it didn't before though, must have missed something.